# Fragment animation issue

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, fragment

Working on simple animation in fragments. I have three fragments where I have to animate the views inside the fragment but the problem I am facing right now is that the animation is not working in the second fragment and when I revisit the fragment then also the animation is not working.

Adapter class

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    Context mContext;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // MainActivity.updatedposition(position);

        if (position == 0)
            return SliderOne.newInstance();
        else if (position == 1)
            return SliderTwo.newInstance();
        else if (position == 2)
            return SliderThree.newInstance();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Slider Activity

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    SliderOne fragment = new SliderOne();
                    fragment.initAnimation(mContext);
                }
                else if (position == 1) {
                    SliderTwo fragment = new SliderTwo();
                    fragment.initAnimation(mContext);
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    SliderThree fragment = new SliderThree();
                    fragment.initAnimation(mContext);
                }
                // Check if this is the page you want.
            }
        });
```

Fragment class

```
public class SliderThree extends Fragment implements PageSelectedAnimation {

    ImageView logo;
    TextView tv_appname;
    CustomTextView tv_msg_2;
    Animation smalltobig, nothingtocome, btnanim;
    Context mContext;

    public static SliderThree newInstance() {
        SliderThree fragment = new SliderThree();
        return fragment;
    }


    public SliderThree() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_three, null);
        mContext = getActivity();
        logo = root.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        tv_appname = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_appname);
        tv_msg_2 = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg_2);
        tv_msg_2.setText(Html.fromHtml("Message other users to negotiate<br><p>the perfect trade or deal.Always</p><p>use your best judgement when</p><p>buying or selling.</p>"));

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void initAnimation(Context mContext) {
        smalltobig = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.smalltobig);
        nothingtocome = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.nothingtocome);
        btnanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.nothingtocome);
        logo.setAnimation(smalltobig);
        logo.setAnimation(nothingtocome);
        tv_appname.setAnimation(btnanim);
    }
}
```

interface created

```
public interface PageSelectedAnimation {

    void initAnimation(Context context);
}
```

Error :-

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.xxx.slider.SliderThree.initAnimation(SliderThree.java:79)
        at com.xxx.activities.SliderActivity$2.onPageSelected(SliderActivity.java:103)

Sharing my code:
[Fragment Code](https://github.com/avik1990/ActFragmentClick-master)

Comment: are you putting those Fragments in a ViewPager?

Comment: @kike shared my full code

Comment: checked, try the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the tags you are using that you are including those Fragments on a ViewPager.

ViewPager charges the current and the adjacents, so they are ready when needed. Therefore you animation runs out of the screen when it is charged.

I would suggest to use `ViewPager.onPageChangeListener`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is the page you want.
    }
});
```

and run the animation method from there.

EDIT:

You can do that nicely creating and implementing an interface on every Fragment.

```
interface PageSelectedAnimation{
    fun initAnimation()
}
```

.

```
public class SliderThree extends Fragment implements PageSelectedAnimation
```

and finally:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        ((PageSelectedAnimation)getYourFragment(position)).initAnimation()
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the code please check.Now it's crashing the app.Not able to find the issue.ClassCastException is coming.

Comment: SliderThree cannot be cast to SliderTwo

Comment: Didn't work.I have followed as you said but it's crashing the app.I am updating my code.Plz review

Comment: Can understand the issue but not getting any solution.Calling a fragment function even before initialization of the view that's why null pointer is coming

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of this question. You should follow the stacktrace and guess why you are getting NPE. Anyway, I can tell you that you are inflating your layout incorrectly, try with `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_three, container, false);`